# json array with inner join

Tags: php, mysql, json, inner-join

i want my json response to be like this

```
{
subtotal="null",
create time ="2017-06-25 11:35:50",

products:[{product name:first,
          price:55}

]}
```

but what i'm getting is this

```
[{subtotal="null", create time ="2017-06-25 11:35:50",

product name:first ,price:55},

]
```

here is my php script

```
 <?php
require "connect.php";


$sql  ="SELECT * FROM products_orders JOIN products ON (products.PRODUCT_CODE =products_orders.PRODUCT_CODE) LEFT JOIN offers ON (offers.OFFER_ID = products_orders.OFFER_ID) ";


$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Error in READING " . mysqli_error($conn));
      $readsarray = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $readsarray[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($readsarray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

    $conn->close();
?>
```

i'm beginner i hope you can help me
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check this answer.

```
$data = array();
$final_data = array();
$products = array();
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
  $data['subtotal'] = $row['subtotal'];
  $data['create time'] = $row['create time'];
  $products['product name'] = $row['product name'];
  $products['price'] = $row['price'];

 $data['products'][] = $products;

 $final_data[] = $data;

}

echo json_encode($final_data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

please check this code this json data store all order detail.

```
 $data = array();
 $final_data = array();
 $products = array();
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $data['subtotal'] = $row['subtotal'];
    $data['create time'] = $row['create time'];
    $products['product name'] = $row['product name'];
    $products['price'] = $row['price'];

   $data['products'] = $products;

   $final_data[] = $data;

 }

echo json_encode($final_data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

$conn->close();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ,i tried it , it made products object not an array

Comment: Do you want the array of products?

Comment: for this please check my new anwer

Answer (score 0):

Try to define $readsarray in this way

```
$i=0;
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$readsarray[$i]["subtotal"] = $row["subtotal"];
$readsarray[$i]["create time"]=$row["create time"];
$readsarray[$i]["products"]=array('product  name'=>$row["product name"],'price'=>$row["price"]);
$i++;
}
 echo json_encode($readsarray,true);

    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: {"PRODUCT_CODE":"15","CUSTOMERID":"2","CREATE_TIME":"2017-06-25 11:36:33","OFFER_ID":null,"SUBTOTAL":null,"DONE":null,"VENDOR_ID":null,"products":{"NAME":"كلوركس مزيل بقع للملابس ","PRICE":"13.75","CATEGORY":"عناية بالمنزل","QUANTITY":"12"}}

Comment: this the response now the products is object not array and it only displayed the first order in the response why is that?

Comment: First try this change I change the code to create a counter so all the response included in the final object if it work with you I will solve the peoples of products

Comment: the counter is working fine now,how can i solve the other problem i want to make products an array of objects

Comment: $readsarray[$i]["products"][]=array('NAME'=>$row["NAME"],'PRICE'=>$row["PRICE"],'CATEGORY'=>$row["CATEGORY"],'QUANTITY'=>$row["QUANTITY"]);
i made it like that and it's working now thank you so much